# EventListener update other entities and infinite loop

Tags: symfony

In my application, i have "users".
One user can have several "accounts"

I have a listener on my "account" entity.
It is declared on "service.yml" file like this :

```
account_listener:
    class: AppBundle\EventListener\AccountListener
    arguments:
        - '@service_container'
    tags:
        - {name: doctrine.event_listener, event: preUpdate}
```

In my service, the method preUpdate :

```
public function preUpdate(PreUpdateEventArgs $eventArgs)
{
    $entity = $eventArgs->getEntity();
    if (!$entity instanceof Account) {
        return;
    }

    $this->container->get('notification_manager')->sendNotification();
}
```

the sendNotification method call a function that try to create an entity "notification"

```
public function sendNotification()
{
    $notification = new Notification();
    $data = array(
                    'label' => 'Hello'
                )
    $form_notif = $this->formFactory->create(NotificationType::class, $notification, ['method' => 'POST']);
    $form_notif->submit($data,($method === 'POST'));
    if ($form_notif->isValid())
    {
        $this->em->persist($notification);
        $this->em->flush();
    } else {
        return $form_notif;
    }
    return $notification;

}
```

**The problem :**
The notification is not created and php is stuck in an infinite loop.

To prevent this, i added this at the beggining of sendNotification method :

```
$eventManager = $this->em->getEventManager();
$eventManager->removeEventListener(['preUpdate'],$this->container->get('account_listener'));
```

With this, it works. But i think there is a better way.

Can you help me ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you call a service which call a `flush`, i think the `removeEventListener` method is the not a bad way to avoid infinite loop.

If you really don't want to call `removeEventListener`, you have to change your pattern and not call flush in a doctrine event.

One alternative is to use a third service with the collection of object you want to flush (in your case, a `NotificationStack` class with a single collection and few getter/setter).

Your `sendNotification` method will add element to this collection (without flushing them).

Then, you can flush all that collection on the `kernel.response` event  (and/or `console.terminate` if needed).

Also, inject the container in a service is a bad pratice, you should inject only needed services and or parameters.

Hope it will helps

Answer (score 0):

the reason for php stuck is as below.

In your code you call the `preUpdate()`, which called when you insert or update the entity....

Now when your sendNotification action will called and you save `Notification()` at that time eventlistener will called, and from eventlistener it again call sendNotification method and so on..... This will create recursive loop, that's why ypur php stuck.

Hope it will help you.